# Spyder 3.3.3 help input box problem: can only type 1 character

Tags: python, python-3.x, spyder

Of course `?function` or `help(function)` is useful. However, Spyder 's help console is  much more elegant with richtext. After updating my spyder to the latest 3.3.3, the problems rised. You can only type one character in the input box.
[image]

I've rebooted it several times but it didn't work. My Spyder environment is in [Winpython](https://winpython.github.io/) .

So how to solve this?

Comment: You can make use of the keyboard shortcut ctrl+I.

Comment: It is a spyder bug. For now you can copy the query you want to search from somewhere and paste it in the search bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer*) This is a bug and it'll be fixed in our next version (**3.3.4**) to be released in March 2019.